# How to hide options button in windows builds of apache cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm trying to remove the button on the left of title bar in Apache Cordova windows builds

[image]

Any idea how to do this? I didn't find anything in the documents or anywhere.

Edit: Idk when , but it seems its now removed by default in newer builds ?